# MySQL How To Use Main Select Value As Subquery Argument?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to construct a query that is a bit more complicated than anything I've done in my limited experience with databases.

```
TABLE:

id - data - type - data3
1 - hello - 1 - 1
2 - goodbye - 1 - 1
3 - goodbye - 1 - 2
4 - goodbye - 2 - 1
5 - hello - 2 - 1
```

The goal is to do 4 things:

1. GROUP the results by "data", but only return one result/row of each
   data type.
2. COUNT the total number of each "data GROUP and return this number.
3. Do this for both "type"=1 and "type"=2, though I only need each
   "data" GROUP item once.
4. the ability to sort results based on each SELECT item.

So the final result returned should be (sorry to be confusing!):

```
data, COUNT(data["type"]=1), COUNT(data["type"]=2 AND data["data"] = data)
```

So, for the sample table above, desired results would be:

```
loop 1 - hello, 2, 1
loop 2 - goodbye, 3, 1
```

Then, ideally, I could sort results by any of these.

This is the query I was trying to construct before resorting to posting this, I don't think it's even close to being correct, but it may help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve a bit better:

```
SELECT 
  (
   SELECT `clicks_network_subid_data`, COUNT(*) 
   FROM track_clicks 
   WHERE `clicks_campaign_id`='$id' AND `clicks_click_type` = '1'
  ) AS keywords, 
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM track_clicks 
   WHERE `clicks_campaign_id`='$id' AND `clicks_click_type` = '2' AND `clicks_network_subid_data` = keywords.clicks_network_subid_data 
  ) AS offer_clicks 
 GROUP BY keywords.clicks_network_subid_data 
 ORDER BY keywords.COUNT(*) DESC
```

I also need to do a JOIN on another table to grab one more piece of data, but I think I can handle that once I get this part figured out.

Comment: sorry, I just edited the question to clarify...  

the problem is that the COUNT(data["type"]=2) needs to count ONLY the data WITH type of 2, from that grouping of "data".    

I edited the original to this:  

data, COUNT(data["type"]=1), COUNT(data["type"]=2 AND data["data"] = data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [IF-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for this

```
SELECT `clicks_network_subid_data`, 
SUM(IF(clicks_click_type` == '1',1,0)) as keywords,
SUM(IF(clicks_click_type` == '2',1,0)) as offer_clicks,
FROM track_clicks 
GROUP BY clicks_network_subid_data
ORDER BY clicks_network_subid_data DESC
```

Comment: problem is that I need to use the `clicks_network_subid_data` as an argument in the SUM(IF(clicks_click_type` == '2',1,0)).  

So how can I do this SUM(IF(clicks_click_type` == '2',1,'clicks_network_subid_data`))  where it will only COUNT the click_type IF it is part of that subid_data GROUPING and TYPE=2

Comment: I think I might have typed that last comment too quickly, testing now :) looks like this might work maybe..

Comment: thanks dude! this ended up working perfectly for what I needed. I didn't know you could do this in mysql - awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT data, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `table` GROUP BY type ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Ordering might become a little slow, as this is a calculated field, but if you don't have a large result set then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is bit not clear , However,  check this query . what I suspect is that you need  count results in columns (single ) instead of rows .

```
select * , count(type_one) as t1_count , count(type_two) as t2_count from (
select  data,if(tmp.type=1,1,0) as type_one, if(tmp.type=2,1,0) as type_two      from  (
    select 1 as id , 'hello' as data , 1 as type , 1 as data3  union
    select 2 as id , 'goodbye' as data , 1 as type , 1 as data3 union
    select 3 as id , 'goodbye' as data , 1 as type , 2 as data3 union
    select 4 as id , 'goodbye' as data , 2 as type , 1 as data3 union
    select 5 as id , 'hello' as data , 2 as type , 1 as data3  
) tmp
) tmp2

group by tmp2.type_one ;
```

let me know if this works for you

cheers :)